# Function is in $L^2$ . how to show that gradient is also in $L^2$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, parabolic-pde

I am dealing with diffusion-reaction equation with three species. I have $L^2$ bound of concentrations. Now I want $L^2$ bound of gradient of concentrations. Somehow if I get $L^4$ or $L^\infty$ bound Of $u_i$, then I can solve my problem. Please help me.

The model is the following system of PDEs for the vector variable ($u_1, u_2, u_3$)
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_t u_1- D_1 \Delta u_1=-k_fu_1u_2+k_b u_3+\theta_1 \\
\partial_t u_2- D_2 \Delta u_2=-k_fu_1u_2+k_b u_3+\theta_2 \\
 \partial_t u_3- D_3 \Delta u_3=k_fu_1u_2-k_b u_3+\theta_3
\end{cases}
$$
where

- $D_i(i=1,2,3), k_b, k_f$ are positive constants and
- $\theta_i(x,t)$ is a function in $L^2$.

**Note**.- I don't have positive solution of diffusion-reaction system.

Comment: It's difficult to help if you don't state the problem explicitly... I don't think there's a general recipe to follow.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by $L^2$ (or other $L^p$ bounds)? (space for positive times, mixed time-space,...)

Comment: @fedja $L^2$ bound means $||u||_{L^2(0,T; \Omega)}$ and $||\nabla u||_{L^2(0,T; \Omega)}$, $\Omega$ is domain.